# Check if `UICollectionView` index path is valid?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to scroll to a specified index path in a `UICollectionView`:

```
if ([self collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0] > self.activeIndexPath.row && self.activeIndexPath.row > 0)
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:self.activeIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionLeft animated:NO];
```

But I keep getting a crash with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x1ff80a30> {length = 2, path = 0 - 40}
```

How can I verify the index path before scrolling? My collection view only has 1 section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check and verify the indexPath that you are passing.

If its ok, try logging the numberofItemsInSection for your collectionView.

Then, try reloading your collectionView before scrolling to the indexPath like:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

Comment: seems to work after reloading the data first, I'll accept if the crash doesn't come up again in the next few days

Comment: @Cbas - sure!! Happy to help :)

Comment: @Cbas - Has your issue been resolved? Please accept the answer if it has been :)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the indexPath of your collectionView for this my code is as  -

**Objective C Code -**

```
- (UIView *)superviewWithClassName:(NSString *)className fromView:(UIView *)view
{
    while (view)
    {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:className])
        {
            return view;
        }
        view = view.superview;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Then I call it from the button handler like so:-

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)
                                [self superviewWithClassName:@"UICollectionViewCell"
                                fromView:button];
    if (cell)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        // do whatever action you need with the indexPath...
    }
}
```

**SWIFT 2.x Code -**

```
func superviewWithClassName(className:String, fromView view:UIView?) -> UIView? {
    guard let classType = NSClassFromString(className) else {
        return nil
    }
    var v:UIView? = view
    while (v != nil) {
        if v!.isKindOfClass(classType) {
            return v
        }
        v = v!.superview
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can access the indexPath from any where you wants on you CollectionView page like this -

```
guard let cell = UIView.superviewWithClassName("UICollectionViewCell", fromView: sender as? UIView) as? UITableViewCell else {return}
```